# Forcing null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am practicing `JUnit` testing and I am not sure what to do when `NullPointerExceptions` occurs.

I am currently creating my own `indexOf()` method and I am comparing it with the original `indexOf()`. I am not sure how to create a similar output from my custom `indexOf()` to have the same output for when the original `indexOf()` has a `NullPointerException`.

I thought about simply giving the output of the error that `NullPointerException` gives me but i am not sure how to do that as well

Here is my code:

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, int ch, int index) {
    if (str == null) {
        // output NullPointerException
    }
    if (str.length <= index || index < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (index == str[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // if not found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Correct your code so that it doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `indexOf()` doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Christian hmm maybe I should have reworded the question a bit better. When ex: str.indexOf(3) and str is null

Comment: So make sure you don't call any methods on null references.

Comment: @Liondancer: Java will always throw an exception in that scenario. You can't even modify this. Its "hardcoded" in every Java virtual machine.

Comment: @CommuSoft I see. So it would be silly to create a condition that deals with this sort of input?

Comment: @Liondancer: I have some problems understanding what you want to do. You create a static method? Normally a list has an instance method to deal with this. But even in this case, you call `str.length`. The java virtual machine will first check if `str` is `null`, in that case a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: @CommuSoft Well I wanted to create a condition where if `str == null` I would forcefully return an output error the same as if a `NullPointerException` occurred. Sorry for the confusion. I see your point about the `str.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf()` never throws a `NullPointerException`, except for `var.indexOf` with `var == null`. And that type of exception is handled automatically by Java.

Your code is however confusing. In most cases `indexOf` is an instance-method. In case of a static method it is of course possible to circumvent the problem. For instance:

```
public static void Foo (Bar b) {
    if(b != null) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This is called a total method: in case `b` is `null`, nothing happens.

However in most cases you write instance methods. When such method is called and the instance is `null`, the Java Virtual Machine will throw a `NullPointerException` itself.

Furthermore in the static method you provide, you call `str.length`, since `str` can be `null`, the Java virtual machine will check this and throw a `NullPointerException` out of the method itself as well.

---

You can however test if an exception is thrown in JUnit using the following pattern:

```
@Test(expected = ExpectedException.class)
public void test () throws ExpectedException {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.methodThatThrowsException();
}
```

JUnit will consider this test to have failed if it does not throw an exception of type `ExpectedException`.

Comment: This is what I meant sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Liondancer: When a `null`-instance calls a method, the Java runtime environment will throw a `NullPointerException` itself. You don't have to do anything for this. That makes `NullPointerException`s one of the most annoying things.

Comment: I appreciate this answer and I seem ot understand what youre saying. I have one last question. I understand that str.length will throw a NullPointerException when str is null. But I was wondering if you knew why I get a `false` when `var.indexOf` throws a `NullPointerExcpetion` when var is `null` (original) and when str.length is called (cusomt)?

Comment: `var.indexOf` will throw a `NullPointerException` as well. Can you provide some code (in your question) to illustrate the problem?

Comment: If you dont mind. Could you take a look at this? I thought because both methods output a `NullPointerException` the test case will return true. But I am assuming it will not due to the error output. http://pastebin.com/tFiKZWhn

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use a fancy little method to handle this.

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, int ch, int index) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(str);
    if (str.length <= index || index < 0) {
```

This method will throw a `NullPointerException` if the given argument is `null`. You can also use it like so:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(str, "The given string cannot be null");
```

To provide your own error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

will do it.  More "organically":

```
Object c = null; c.toString();
```

will do it.

But note that `indexOf` does not throw NPEs.